# Send email from a Google Apps nickname on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

I'm trying to set-up a business website using App Engine. Previously, I had prototyped the site using my personal gmail account, but now I've purchased a domain name and have set-up google apps. So far, the only hitch I've encountered is getting my contact form to properly email people who try to contact me. Originally, I was using this code:

```
from google.appengine.api import mail

sender_email = "Admin <admin@example.appspotmail.com>"
mail.send_mail(sender_email, contact_email, subject, body)
```

I'd like to change `sender_email` to `guru@example.com` where `guru` is a "nickname" for my email account on Google Apps.

When I try to add `guru@example.com` I can receive an invitation email but can't add the nickname as a separate account.

Is there any way to do this without adding a new mailbox to my Google Apps account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a new mailbox.

I spent some time researching this issue and found no work arounds.  Outside of possibly using [Python E-Mail library](http://docs.python.org/library/email) and my initial look into it seemed more effort than it was worth for my applications.  You will also need to host an email server somewhere and configure your mail exchange records in DNS properly.

If you do write your own email sending function and you're changing the sender your message will likely be flagged as spam.

Also if you plan on processing or receiving mail using your App Engine app it will need to be addressed to user@myapp.appspotmail.com as well.  Thus negating all that extra effort to keep from using appspotmail.com

Comment: Once you have a mailbox set up for guru@example.com, you can sign into Gmail for that account and set up forwarding to user@myapp.appspotmail.com.  If you add guru@example.com as a view-only developer for the app, you can both send and receive mail with that address, without exposing appspotmail to users.

Comment: Yes that will allow both sending and receiving on your guru@example.com, but I have read that there are sometimes issues with mail forwarding delaying/not delivering.  I have not experienced any issues myself though.

Just a fyi of something you should stay alert about